# NGINX restrict query parameters

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, query-string

Is there any simple way of restricting query parameters using NGINX?
By this I mean there is a set of allowed query parameters (that are used by the application), any other query parameters should be eliminated. Essentially a whitelist of allowed parameters

- I'm looking to do this without redirecting the user.
- There is no specific order in which the parameters will appear in the 
  query string.
- If a request contains a both parameters that are allowed and
  those that are not allowed, then the allowed parameters are
  maintained.

For example: If i allow parameters A, B, C then:

- the query string ?A=x&B=y&C=z is perfectly fine.
- the query string is ?A=x&K=j&C=z&B=y then it would be rewritten to be A=x&C=z&B=y (the "K" parameter was removed, "K" could be anything)
- the query string ?K=j is removed entirely

Most of the answers I have found discuss removing specific query parameters, or removing the entire query string.

Answer (score 1):

If your whitelist is relatively short, you can construct resulting URI from scratch like this:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://backend/$1?A=$arg_a&B=$arg_b&C=$arg_c;
}
```

In this case some of parameters might be empty if not present in original request.
Or you can use Lua, njs or perl module.